# Adaptive dialogs with Bot framework skills sample

Tags: botframework, adaptive-design

Based on this [Release Notes](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/releases/tag/4.9#Skills) it looks like Skills have been updated to work with adaptive dialogs, and both adaptive and traditional dialogs will now accept all types of activities.

Is there any example code to see how to use Adaptive dialogs in Bf skills for node? I didn't find in [samples](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [`BeginSkill`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-adaptive-dialog-actions#beginskill) action. There is a document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-connect-to-a-skill) that shows you how to do this in Composer.

Comment: I meant how to use adaptive dialogs in existing BF skill bot instead of standard waterfall dialog

Comment: Adaptive dialogs are still in preview for Node, so the samples can be found in the [experimental](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/experimental/adaptive-dialog/javascript_nodejs) folder. You use adaptive dialogs in a skill the same way you'd use them in any other bot. If you're encountering a problem that specifically has to do with using adaptive dialogs in skills then you need to ask a question about that problem specifically rather than just generally asking "how to do it." Is this answer acceptable?

Comment: Please remember to upvote and accept the answer if it helps you